# Issues setting $PATH on Bash on Ubuntu on Windows (Linux Subsystem)

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, terraform, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using the "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows" (Linux Subsystem) and want to add Terraform to my $PATH. Since Terraform can't be installed via apt-get, I did the following steps:

1. Navigated to this directory, where I wanted to install Terraform:

   **cd /usr/local**
2. In the above path, I used wget to download Terraform:

   **wget 
   https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/0.9.8/terraform_0.9.8_linux_amd64.zip**
3. Terraform successfully unzips! When I open the file in VIM it is all good:

   **unzip terraform_0.9.8_linux_amd64.zip**
4. I then enter this command to check to see if the Terraform binary is accessible from the command line:

   **terraform -version**

However the following message gets returned:

```
terraform: command not found
```

This tells me that the Terraform downloaded location needs to be added to my $PATH.

5. Already being logged in as the root user ("sudo su") I enter the following command to access ".profile":

**vim ~/.profile**

The following is already in this file, which I leave untouched:

```
 # ~/.profile: executed by Bourne-compatible login shells.

 if [ "$BASH" ]; then
   if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
     . ~/.bashrc
   fi
 fi

 mesg n
```

Immediately below this text, I add the following, and successfully save the file using **:wq!**:

```
 export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
 export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/terraform
```

6.
I then again enter the following command to check to see if terraform is detected

**terraform -version**

Still the same "terraform: command not found" message is returned. I even tried closing out and starting a new command line session and even restarting my computer. Still no change.

Anyone have any ideas on how to resolve this? Again, note that I am using "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows" (Linux Subsystem). Any input would be appreciated!

Comment: I'll boot Win10 with WSL in a bit to confirm, but make sure Ubuntu uses (sources) `~/.profile` and not `~/.bash_profile`. Some distros use one or the other and I don't recall what Ubuntu does. E.g., SuSE does the former and Archlinux does the latter.

Comment: Downloading the zip package to a system location is weird and sloppy. `/usr/local` is probably a good destination for *installing* the thrngs you extract from the zip (libraries to `/usr/local/lib`, binaries to `/usr/local/bin`, etc) and if you do it correctly, you probably don't need to update your `PATH` or other system configuration settings. Traditionally, the tarball (not zip) would contain a `configure` script which creates a `Makefile` or something which allows you to run a simple script to install (and uninstall) the package.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The direct answer to your problem is at the end.
But I think it will make more sense if you keep reading from here.

Before trying to add to `PATH`,
I recommend to test a program first.
In your case I would do like this:

```
wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/0.9.8/terraform_0.9.8_linux_amd64.zip
unzip terraform_0.9.8_linux_amd64.zip
./terraform
```

Notice the last line `./terraform`.
The zip file contains a single file, `terraform`,
which now should be in the current directory,
so I can run it with `./terraform`.
If it's executable.
If it's not executable then confirm it:

```
ls -l terraform
```

And make it executable if needed:

```
chmod +x terraform
```

Now let's add it to `PATH`.
But first,
let's decide where to put this executable.
`/usr/local/bin` seems a reasonable location.
So let's move the `terraform` executable into that directory.

Usually `/usr/local/bin` is already on `PATH`,
so you might not need to change anything.
Now you can try your check, and there's a good chance it already works:

```
terraform -version
```

If it doesn't, then `/usr/local/bin` is not on the `PATH`.
To add it, add this line in `~/.profile`:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

---

Two things looked fundamentally wrong with your approach:

1. Adding `/usr/local/terraform` to `PATH`. This is fishy, because the entries on `PATH` must be directories, and in your post nothing indicates that you created a directory at `/usr/local/terraform`.

   - You `cd` into `/usr/local`, and then `unzip` the zip file of terraform. The linked zip contains a single file named `terraform`, so `/usr/local/terraform` in your example should be a file.
   - If it is a file, then you could make it executable as `terraform` by adding to add to `PATH` its base directory. But adding `/usr/local` to `PATH` would not be a good idea. It's conventional to put binaries into `/usr/local/bin`, not directly into `/usr/local`
2. You did not mention how you reloaded `~/.profile`. After editing this file, the new commands you added do not get automatically executed in your current shell. They will get executed when you open a new shell. Or you could manually execute the added commands in the current shell.

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks so much @janos! Beautifully explained! I appreciate the effort as well @David! The issue appears to be because I had not stored the file in `usr/local/bin`. The idea of adding `/usr/local/terraform` to the PATH as well as storing it at that directory path was from a tutorial I was following off the net, so I blindly followed it, assuming he knew something I didn't lol!

Comment: @user791134 it's good you described all your steps accurately, it made it easy to pinpoint the problem. Few askers do this (and they are less likely to get good answers: a loss for all). So well done to you too!

Comment: When you say `So let's move the terraform executable into that directory...` (`usr/local/bin`), do you mean running `mv terraform /user/local/bin` directly? OR is there another method for this?

Answer (score 0):

Hit below command

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

Comment: I don't think this answer adds anything that isn't already covered in the detailed accepted answer.